# Define custom aliases for outlook contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, contacts, alias

I have a close coworker whom I email almost daily.  Let's call her "Leigh Wilson".  The global address book at my company has several other people with the first name "Leigh" and/or the last name "Wilson", so when I create a new email I can't just type `leigh` or `wilson` or even `lwilson` in the `To:` field -- I have to type out `leigh wilson`.

How can I make it so that I can type something short (e.g. `lw`) and have Outlook know that means "Leigh Wilson"?

I tried adding her to my local contact list and then filling in the `Nickname` field (on the details tab).  I also tried creating a distribution list named `lw` with her as the only member.  Neither worked.

I'm using Outlook 2007 if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, found it.  Open the address book (`Tools -> Address Book ...`).  Then, open `Tools -> Options ...`.  Then move the (local) `Contacts` address list above the `Global Address List` list.

This way, Outlook seems to treat my local "Leigh Wilson" contact as a definitive match, and doesn't bother me to disambiguate it against the entire global address list.